# $TSU(n)$ completely integrable with 3 $SU(2)$ invariant functions?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry, moment-map

Consider the Lie group $SU(n)$ endowed with the standard bi-invariant metric. Then $SU(n)$ can be viewed as a symmetric space of $K_{n,n} := SU(n) \times SU(n)$.

Define $M := K_{n,n} /SU(n)$. Using our bi-invariant metric on $SU(n)$, we get a symplectic structure on $TM$ and a momentum map $\Phi \colon TM \to \mathfrak{k}_{n,n}^*$

Consider now the following chain of Lie subgroups
$$\{1\}\subset U(1) \times \{1\} \subset U(2)\times \{1\} \subset \dots \subset U(n-1) \times \{1\} \subset SU(n) \times \{1\} \subset SU(n) \times U(1)\subset \dots \subset SU(n) \times SU(n),$$
where $U(j-1)$ is embedded in the down-right corner of $U(j)$.

For convinience lets write $K_{i,j}=U(i) \times U(j)$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n-1$ and $K_{n,j} = SU(n) \times U(j)$ for $0 \leq j \leq n-1$.
So our chain becomes 
$$K_{0,0} \subset K_{1,0} \subset \dots \subset K_{n,0} \subset K_{n,1} \subset \dots \subset K_{n,n}.$$

We can now construct $K_{i,j}$-invariant functions on the corresponding Lie algebras $\mathfrak{k}_{i,j}$ and using the projections we can pull-back these functions to $\mathfrak{k}_{n,n}$. Using the bi-invariant metric we can identify $\mathfrak{k}_{n,n}$ and $\mathfrak{k}_{n,n}^*$. 
Using the momentum map we are able to show, that we get $n^2-1$ functions on $TM$, which Poisson-commute and which are functionally independent almost everywhere.

My question now is:

Is it possible to construct functions $f_1, \dots, f_{n^2-1}$ on $\mathfrak{k}_{n,n}^*$ such that the pull-backs $\Phi^*f_1, \dots, \Phi^*f_{n^2-1}$ Poisson-commute and are functionally independent almost everywhere and such that 3 of them are invariant under the lifted action of $SU(2)$ on $TSU(n) \cong T\left(SU(n) \times_{SU(n)} SU(n)\right)$?